# What's the meaning behind the text in the intro of Sabagebu?

Tags: sabagebu

During the intro of Sabagebu! There are some random english sentences that scroll across the screen like:

"You are a real follower of our survival gamers. Its fantastic to be atrocious. You must be the one beyond good and evil."

"____ be so easy if they apologise to us for it"

and several other weird sentences.

[image: Intro]

I found it strange when I watched it initially, because it doesn't seem like it would be from a blurb or an extract from the original source.

Does anyone know what the sentences mean and what they are a reference to? They don't seem to be translated lyrics anyway.